# Does a pseudoreflection, restricted to a proper invariant subspace, equal the identity map?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Definition:**
*Let $V$ be a finite dimensional, complex vectorspace. Then we call $g \in GL(V)$ a [pseudoreflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreflection), if the rank of $g - Id$ is $1$. Furthermore $c=det(g)$ is called special eigenvalue of $g$.*

---

**My question:**

Assume that $g$ is a pseudoreflection on $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ and consider the $g$-invariant subspace $V_1 \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $V_2 = \mathbb{C}^n / V_1$. Now does, $g$ being a pseudoreflection imply, that either $g$ restricted to $V_1$ or $V_2$ resp. is the identity?

---

**My idea:**
First we note, that by the $g$-invariance we have $gV_1 \subset V_1$. Since  $char(\mathbb{C})=0$, in the case $c \neq 1$, $g$ is diagonalizable and can be represented as a matrix $g=diag(1,...,1,c)$. So $g$ is by definition the identity on a $n-1$ dimensional subspace and $c$ can´t be $1$. Now let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be the standart basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Consider $\{e_1,...,e_{n-1}\}$ as basis of $V_1$. Then by the above observations, the matrix which represents $g$ maps
$$e_i \mapsto e_i.$$
So we conclude $g \mid_{V_1} = Id$. As for the complementary space,we take the corresponding eigenvector to the eigenvalue $c$ as basisvector.

And then i have a somewhat "additional" question about the notation, as of why $det(g)$ is refered to as "special eigenvalue"? I noticed, that a pseudoreflection of an $n$-dim. v.sp. alsways has the eigenvalue $1$ of multiplicity $n-1$ and one eigenvalue $c$ of multiplicity $1$. So in partivular, it is diagonalizable/triagonalizable and thus $det(g) = 1 \cdot ... \cdot 1 \cdot c=c$ is exactly the product of the diagonal entries. So is this just an odd way to say, that $det(g)$ itself is an eigenvalue of $g$, or is there a deeper meaning behind this?

Comment: Careful writing $\Bbb C^n\backslash V_1$. That is not at all what you mean. You mean the orthogonal complement?

Comment: You are right, i mean $\mathbb{C}^n / V_1$.

Comment: But be careful. That is a quotient, not a subspace, of $V$.

Comment: Well, this is the notoation in the proof i´m reading and trying to understand (therefor this question)

Comment: But you wrote the quotient is a subspace; it is not. Maybe you should edit to reproduce the proof accurately.

Comment: I hope its a bit better edited now. What i tried to prove, was the case for $V_1$. I don´t know, how to proceed in the case  for $V_2$.

Comment: By definition $g$ is the identity on an $(n-1)$-dimensional space and the remaining eigenvalue, $c$, cannot be $1$. Just take the corresponding eigenvector to span the complementary subspace.